# Character classes in regular expressions should not contain the same character twice Sonar cube issue

Tags: javascript

I have written a regex as below but it is giving me sonar cube issue saying " Character classes in regular expressions should not contain the same character twice"

```
var17regex =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9,-_]*$/;
```

Currently it is showing 2 duplicate issues for this regex.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oi0q.png)

Any suggestions on how to modify the above regex to fix this sonar cube issue ?

Comment: The part `,-_` means "all characters whose character codes lie in the range from "," to "_". It does *not* mean "comma, dash, underscore". If you want to put a "-" in a character group like that, it should be the last thing before `]`.

Comment: @Pointy so can I use [A-z0-9] instead of the one I'm using so that it will cover all ASCII from 65 to 122?

Comment: Yes but be aware that between "Z" and "a" there are other characters you may not want.